# Access-based enumeration and subfolders

Tags: network-share, file-permissions, file-sharing

Is there a way, using ABE to let users get to subfolders they have access to, in folders they don't have access to?

Example

\[sharedrive]\shares\accounting\group1\bills\

shares is set to everyone can read

accounting is set to only group act can read/write

bills is set to only group contractors can read/write

I want contractors to be able to start in shares and go through the folders to get to bills without having to give list rights to contractors for the folders they need to go through. I know that would be easier but the actual share drive I am working with is huge with tons of different share permissions, there would be tons of folder permissions to change to get ABE to work.

EDIT:

***WITHOUT having to give list rights on all other folders.***

If it is not possible just let me know. I am asking because as I said before there would be a TON of permissions to change if I had to go through and change permissions on all the folders in the path.